# How can I enforce activation of maven profiles with full bool logic?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-enforcer-plugin

I have the following case that is not covered by maven-enforcer-plugin (https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/index.html):

5 profiles:

- scala-2.11
- scala-2.12
- spark-2.2
- spark-2.3
- spark-2.4

and the following enforcement rules:

- exact one of scala 2.11 & 2.12 must be activated
- exact one of spark 2.2, 2.3 & 2.4 must be activated
- spark 2.2 & 2.3 is not compatible with scala 2.12

The existing maven plugin is too weak to implement this. What other options do I have?

Answer (score 2):

It is relatively straightforward to write your own enforcer rule. I would aim for that.

On the other hand, I would check if it is really necessary to have all these profiles and to activate/deactivate them by command line.